# Taylor Series Expansion only upto two terms.

Tags: taylor-expansion, approximation, newton-raphson

0 = $f(x_{r}) = f(x_{n}) + f'(x_{n})(x_{r}-x_{n}) + \frac{f''(\xi)}{2}(x_{r}-x_{n})^{2}$

I came across a Taylor series expansion as shown in above equation while studying proof for convergence of [Newton-Raphson method](https://nptel.ac.in/content/storage2/courses/122104019/numerical-analysis/Rathish-kumar/ratish-1/f3node7.html). I am not able to understand why the series has been terminated after writing 3 terms only and what exactly has $\xi$ to do in the third term. $\xi$ is a number between $x_{r}$ and $x_{n}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last term is the remainder term of the Taylor series truncated to first order. Say you have a function $f(x)$. $\textit{Formally,}$ you can Taylor expand and write $f(x)=T_k(x)+R_k(x),$ where $T_k(x)$ is the $k$-th degree Taylor polynomial and $R_k(x)$ is the $k$-th remainder term. In your example, $k=1$, and you have a linear Taylor polynomial with the Taylor remainder being the last term involving the derivative evaluated at $\xi$, i.e.

$$R_1(x)=\frac{f''(\xi)}{2}(x_r-x_n)^2$$

for some $\xi\in(x_r,x_n).$

Comment: I wouldn't say $\xi$ alone is the remainder, rather the term involving it, with $\xi$ restricted but unknown in an interval.

Comment: I of course didn't intend to convey $\xi$ itself is the remainder. I meant the term with $\xi$. Edited the answer for clarity. OP already specified where $\xi$ must live, and this is also included in the definition of Taylor remainder.

Comment: @coffeemath Forgot to tag. Not sure if you received.

Comment: @Stuck-- Got it.

Comment: In addition to what @Stuck mentioned, this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yUUPP70Fhpo) might help in clarifying why and how the error term (remainder term) is that.